# developer public key

Tags: android

is the key you get from your developer page something that needs to be protected/hidden in your app when you put it in the market? Or will nothing happen if someone decompiles the app and gets the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Google says about it:

> To keep your public key safe from
>   malicious users and hackers, do not
>   embed it in any code as a literal
>   string. Instead, construct the string
>   at runtime from pieces or use bit
>   manipulation (for example, XOR with
>   some other string) to hide the actual
>   key. The key itself is not secret
>   information, but you do not want to
>   make it easy for a hacker or malicious
>   user to replace the public key with
>   another key.

From [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_best_practices.html).